# Chirp Arduino example not detecting chirps

Tags: arduino, chirp

I am trying to make the Nano33SenseReceive example of the ChirpSDK 3.4.0 work on a newly bought Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense.

I have added my credentials to the credentials.h file and uploaded the sketch to the board. I am playing the sounds from the vimeo videos embedded in [this Arduino Project Hub page](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/ChirpDevs/send-data-with-sound-bf7024) using my laptop speakers but nothing gets printed on the serial monitor and the LED does not turn on.

To test if the sketch starts, I added a line:

```
Serial.println("Serial started.");
```

just after the:

```
while (!Serial);
```

and it prints the line just fine, once I open the serial monitor, so it seems the sketch is running properly. This, however, is the only thing I get on the monitor, no matter how many times I play the sounds.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

(Edited after responses by Dinu and joerobot)

I have managed to make it listen by using `16khz-mono-embedded`. However, although the code now hears the sound, it fails to parse it. Here is example output from the monitor:

```
Chirp SDK initialised.
Receiving data...
Received data: ⸮
Receiving data...
Received data: 
Receiving data...
Received data: 
Receiving data...
Received data: 
Receiving data...
Received data: 
Receiving data...
Received data: 
Receiving data...
Received data: 
Receiving data...
Received data: ⸮
Receiving data...
Received data: ⸮
```

On the plus side, I had absolutely no idea a left-to-right flipped question mark existed so can't complain much. On the minus side it's a bit disappointing to see that the mic can't figure out a chirp at a few centimeters from the speaker in a quiet room. Having said that, it's still early days so I 'm hoping future version of the SDK will iron out performance issues.

(Edited to add hardware details)

I have tried two laptops, one Clevo with Onkyo speakers and an Intel sound card and one Lenovo X1.
I have also tried my phone, Lenovo K33a48.

In all cases, I uploaded a fresh copy of the example file in `File > Examples > ChirpSDK > Nano33SenseReceive` and played the vimeo videos embedded in [this page](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/ChirpDevs/send-data-with-sound-bf7024) at full volume, right next to the Arduino. [Here](https://vimeo.com/353015228) is a direct vimeo link to one of the videos.

Every time, I get the`Receiving data...` message, showing that the transmission is understood as such but then I get the empty `Received data:`, occasionally with the left to right question mark.

Comment: The payloads are being transmitted in byte array format, check out [developers documentation](https://developers.chirp.io/docs/using-chirp/payloads#hexstrings) for more information about how to convert the payload to string or hex-string.

Regarding the performance, in your environment, you should be able to decode the payload meters away. Can you give us more information about that? What device are you using to send data, what volume and a recording would be great if you can share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue too - turns out the problem isn't in the receiver at all, but in the data being sent.

For whatever reason, the videos that you linked that should be sending RGB values just seem to give the backwards ?.

If you use [messenger.chirp.io](https://messenger.chirp.io/) to generate sounds then the message will be displayed correctly in the serial monitor.

Comment: Yup, this link worked perfectly. The problem is actually with the Vimeo videos embedded in the Arduino Project Hub page.

Answer (score 2):

The config string from the credentials.h correspond to a specific protocol. Make sure your app on the developer's website is set with the correct protocol , which is 16khz mono in the video if I'm not wrong.

As Joe mentioned, `16khz-mono-embedded` needs to be used for Arduino

Comment: The 16khz-mono-embedded protocol must be used for Arduino